ArcGIS Pro publishing map/feature service from featueclass and joined dynamic table (db view)
I need to join a dynamic PostGIS database view "measurements" to a static SDE geodatabase point featureclass "locations"  (same SDE/PostGIS geodatabase). They have the same number of rows but data in the collumns of the db view "measurements change when the db view updates based on new data added to the underlying source db tables of the view. I want my point featureclass to have field values of the latest data from a sensor stored in a DB and processed in the "measurement" db view. And I want to publish that result together as a Map/Feature service that shows always the latest data and show it in the webmapapp.
How do I join some of the fields of the dynamic view to the point featureclass and publish the service so I always have the current data in the resulting Map/Feature service?
